# UINavigationBar barTintColor effects color of time, battery indicator. Change their color

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

the following line of code effects the topmost color of the iOS data: time, network data, a battery indicator.

When I set the `barTintColor` to black the data is invisible because it is black by default.

How to change the color of the system data from black to white?

Comment: The @user3723612 means UINavigationBarInstance.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

Comment: You mean "make the bar black this way instead of the way you did?"

Comment: No, it is an answer to the question in the first post.

Comment: Yes, I'm with  Dave Schweisguth on this one.